# EC2Config + forward logs and metrics to cloudwatch

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an existing Windows EC2 instance and I'd like to enable custom metrics to Cloudwatch and forward logs to Cloudwatch Logs. I understand that I need to install EC2Config agent to do this. Since this is an already provisioned instance I'm unable to use an IAM role for passing credentials. Will I be able to use an IAM User with the correct policy to do this i.e can I hardcode the access key and secret key in EC2config somewhere?

Also for enabling Cloudwatch Custom Metrics + Logs is it simply a tick box that enables it?

Will EC2Config have any undesired impact on the OS, I can see many options around password changes and formatting EBS volumes - I assume if i leave those options alone it enable itself, since I'm only interested in forwarding logs to cloudwatch.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You asked several questions, i will try to address them.

1. You cannot assign an IAM role to an instance after it has been created.
2. I would try to install the [AWS cli tools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html) and use [aws configure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html) to check if the EC2Config agent can use it
3. The agent sends the logs to CloudWatch. As it is an Agent running it does consume system resources but it should be minimal.

Comment: Thanks hopefully the CLI will prompt me for a access and secret key